# Parallel curve is simple - Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, rotations, orthogonality, plane-curves

I'm struggling with the injectivity of the parallel curve.

Let $\alpha:[0,\ell]\to\mathbb R^2$ with $0<\ell\in\mathbb R$ be a planar closed simple regular curve parametrized by arc length, and its normal always points inside the region it bounds. Let $0\neq r\in\mathbb R$ and define the parallel curve $\alpha_r:[0,\ell]\to\mathbb R^2$ as $\alpha_r(s):=\alpha(s)+rN(s)$, being $N(s)$ the unit normal vector of $\alpha$ in $\alpha(s)$.

I have to show that there is $r$ such that $\alpha_r$ is a simple curve.

**Attempt:** In the traditional way, let be $s_1, s_2 \in [0,\ell)$ where $\alpha_r(s_1)=\alpha_r(s_2)$ and let's try to prove that $s_1=s_2$. From the previous equation and by definition of $\alpha_r$ we can obtain $\alpha(s_1) - \alpha(s_2)=-r[N(s_1)-N(s_2)]$ and because we have planar curves $N(s) = JT(s)$ where $J$ is the rotation of 90° degress (in the desired direction) and $T(s)=\alpha'(s)$. Therefore $\alpha(s_1) - \alpha(s_2) = J(-r[\alpha'(s_1) - \alpha'(s_2)])$ which implies that $\alpha(s_1) - \alpha(s_2)$ and $\alpha'(s_1) - \alpha'(s_2)$ are orthogonal, this is $\langle\alpha(s_1) - \alpha(s_2),\alpha'(s_1) - \alpha'(s_2)\rangle=0$

Here is the stuck! I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Remember that you want to find an $r$ that works. In fact, it should work for $r<r_0$. Consider the values $r(s)$ so that $\alpha(s)+r(s)N(s)$ is again a point on the curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't think i understand your hint, how do you define $r_0$? Also $r$ is fixed as a constant, so why consider a function $r(s)$?

Comment: I'm choosing $r(s)$ to be the smallest positive $r$ so that $\alpha(s)+rN(s)$ is a point on the curve. Unfortunately, $r(s)$ does not vary continuously, but it is semicontinuous. We want to choose $r_0$ to be the minimum of all such $r(s)$.  Why must this minimum be positive? You need an upper bound on curvature. For a curve like $\alpha(t)=t^2\sin(1/t)$, there will be problems.